# Using mongodb how to retrive part of document seaching on an Array of Document fields

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing project using mongodb. so here I need to retrieve only selected fields of the document searching on an Array of Document elements. this is my example.

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$id": "515ce66ca00b2aa30a000000"
        },
        "user_id": "user_1111",
        "events": [
            {
                "subject": "it test I",
                "start_date": "04/14/2013",
                "start_time": "8.00 AM",
                "end_date": "04/14/2013",
                "end_time": "10.30 AM",
                "all_day_event": "false",
                "discription": "no discription",
                "location": "STC",
                "private": "false",
                "time_zone": "IST",
                "alarm": "true",
                "alarm_threshold": "5",
                "status": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
```

so here I need to retrieve following result.

```
           {
                "subject": "it test I",
                "start_date": "04/14/2013",
                "start_time": "8.00 AM",
                "end_date": "04/14/2013",
                "end_time": "10.30 AM",
                "all_day_event": "false",
                "discription": "no discription",
                "location": "STC",
                "private": "false",
                "time_zone": "IST",
                "alarm": "true",
                "alarm_threshold": "5",
                "status": "true"
            }
```

searching

> {"events.subject":"it test I"} 
>   how I do this. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a straightforward way to do what you want but you can try the following:

1. If events can be **no more than 1** in a document you can just do a projection:

   ```
   db.events.find({"events.subject":"it test I"},{events:1,_id:0}).pretty()
   {
       "events" : [
           {
               "subject" : "it test I",
               "start_date" : "04/14/2013",
               "start_time" : "8.00 AM",
               "end_date" : "04/14/2013",
               "end_time" : "10.30 AM",
               "all_day_event" : "false",
               "discription" : "no discription",
               "location" : "STC",
               "private" : "false",
               "time_zone" : "IST",
               "alarm" : "true",
               "alarm_threshold" : "5",
               "status" : "true"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   However you will still get the result in a key-value format. If you are using a driver, perhaps, you can easily retrieve the value.
2. If events can be **more than 1** in a document, I'm afraid you can only get the first matching subdocument for each matching document using `$elemMatch`:

   ```
   db.events.find({"events.subject":"it test I"},{events:{$elemMatch:{"subject":"it test I"}},_id:0}).pretty()
   ```

   And you get the same result as in no. 1.
3. You can try the aggregation framework which you can use to retrieve all matching documents:

   ```
   db.events.aggregate(
   {$match: {"events.subject":"it test I"}},
   {$unwind: "$events"},
   {$match: {"events.subject":"it test I"}},
   {
     $project:{
       _id: 0,
       subject: "$events.subject",
       start_date: "$events.start_date",
       end_date: "$events.end_date",
       end_time: "$events.end_time",
       all_day_event: "$events.all_day_event",
       discription: "$events.discription",
       location: "$events.location",
       private: "$events.private",
       time_zone: "$events.time_zone",
       alarm: "$events.alarm",
       alarm_threshold: "$events.alarm_threshold",
       status: "$events.status"
     }
   })
   {
       "result" : [
           {
               "subject" : "it test I",
               "start_date" : "04/14/2013",
               "end_date" : "04/14/2013",
               "end_time" : "10.30 AM",
               "all_day_event" : "false",
               "discription" : "no discription",
               "location" : "STC",
               "private" : "false",
               "time_zone" : "IST",
               "alarm" : "true",
               "alarm_threshold" : "5",
               "status" : "true"
           }
       ],
       "ok" : 1
   }
   ```